# What is the correct way of removing classes from multiple tags in HTML through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, simple-html-dom, typescript

This code works fine:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    let inactiveClass = document.getElementsByClassName(`nonactive`)
    console.log(inactiveClass)
    inactiveClass[1].classList.remove(`nonactive`)
    inactiveClass[0].classList.remove(`nonactive`)
}, 1000)
```

But as soon as i alter the last two lines as

```
setTimeout(function(){
    let inactiveClass = document.getElementsByClassName(`nonactive`)
    console.log(inactiveClass)
    inactiveClass[0].classList.remove(`nonactive`)
    inactiveClass[1].classList.remove(`nonactive`)
}, 1000)
```

console tells me

```
script.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a **live** HTMLCollection of found elements.

Every time you remove one item, the collection is smaller. So when you remove [0] there is no [1] left

so you need to do it reverse, OR use another class that stays OR use a static list like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(`.nonactive`)]
  .forEach(inact => inact.classList.remove(`nonactive`));
}, 1000)
```

```css
.nonactive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nonactive">Non active</div>
<div class="nonactive">Non active</div>
<div class="nonactive">Non active</div>
<div class="nonactive">Non active</div>
<div class="nonactive">Non active</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the HTMLCollection changes as soon as you update an element inside the HTMLCollection. So you have to start your iteration from the end instead of the start of the HTMLCollection...

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  let inactiveClasses = document.getElementsByClassName(`nonactive`)
  for (let i = inactiveClasses.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const inactiveClass = inactiveClasses[i];
    inactiveClass.classList.remove(`nonactive`)
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
div {
  color: green;
}

.nonactive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nonactive">test1</div>
<div class="nonactive">test2</div>
<div class="nonactive">test3</div>
<div class="nonactive">test4</div>
```

Comment: It is not an array but an HTMLCollection as I pointed out in my answer

Comment: Oh, i wasn't aware of this being a difference! thanks for the correction :)